# Filter Group of Items in Django And Display List of Groups

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display a nav menu for my website of minerals. The nav would display a list of the available mineral categories.  A user that clicks on a 'category' will see a list of each mineral in that category.

I've tried to accomplish this via template tag but nothing is printing and in django debug bar i don't see the SQL executing--so not sure what the issue is.

my Mineral model

```
class Mineral(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    image_filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image_caption = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    formula = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    strunz_classification = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    crystal_system = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    unit_cell = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    crystal_symmetry = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cleavage = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mohs_scale_hardness = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    luster = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    streak = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    diaphaneity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    optical_properties = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    refractive_index = models.CharField(max_length=755)
    crystal_habit = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    specific_gravity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

my template tag

```
 from django import template

register = template.Library()

categories = ["Silicates", "Oxides", "Sulfates", "Sulfides", "Carbonates", "Halides", "Sulfosalts", "Phosphates",
              "Borates", "Organic Minerals", "Arsenates", "Native Elements", "Other"]


@register.inclusion_tag('minerals/mineral_nav.html')
def nav_minerals_list():
    return {'categories': categories}
```

mineral_nav.html

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <a href="{% url 'minerals:category' category=category%}">{{ category }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

category url

```
url(r'^(?P<category>[\w\s]+)/$', views.search_category, name='category')
```

search_category view

```
def search_category(request,category):
    minerals = Mineral.objects.filter(category__iexact=category)
    return render(request,'minerals/mineral_list.html', {'minerals':minerals})
```

and then just trying to call the menu on my home page like this:

```
 {%nav_minerals_list%}
```

note i am also definitely importing the template tags in my html page.

any ideas?

UPDATE -- i fixed the template tag but i'm getting the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'category' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['minerals/(?P<category>[a-zA-Z])/$']
```

UPDATE 2 -I've changed the code around a bit to be what I believe to be a bit better form, but I'm still getting a new reverse match error.  The error is as follows:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'category' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'category': 'Silicates'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['minerals/(?P<category>[a-zA-Z])/$']
```

So guess a good sign that it is picking up one of the category names but still not sure why this isn't working.  Any ideas?

UPDATE 3
noticed a problem with my REGEX for the URL so changed that.  I now have the categories printing out correctly with links so that they are going to the correct url--i.e (http://localhost:8000/minerals/Silicates/) BUT the list of minerals for that category are not printing out

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
{% nav_minerals_list %}
```

for more refer this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: yes you are right woops, i am still getting an error: Reverse for 'category' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['minerals/(?P<category>[a-zA-Z])/$']

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in your li tag,

```
{% for mineral in minerals %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'minerals:category' mineral.category %}">{{ mineral.category }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks--tried that and got NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'category' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['minerals/(?P<category>[a-zA-Z])/$']